# Simplifying partial derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, laplace-method

I am working my way through a textbook on the heat equation as an example o applied partial differential equations. Richard Habberman fourth edition if anyone is curious.  Section 2.5 is about Laplace's Equation for a steady state of heat ow in a rectangle. It has a simplification I do not understand.  Forgive me I am a neuroscience major not a math major.

Given a partial differential eqn

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0
$$

We are looking for product solutions.
let...
$u(x,y)=h(x)phi(y) $
Here u is temperature and phi is the heat flux.  I have no idea what h is or where it came from.  In fact I don't even get where the above equation came from at all. I assume it came from some other thermal relation.  This is besides the point for my question.

Then we substitute the second into the first which gives us...
$$phi(y)\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2}+h(x)\frac{\partial^2 phi}{\partial y^2}=0
$$

So if a function like h(x) is in the same terms as a derivative, it can simply be taken away and made to be the new top of the derivative?  IS there an identity I should know to understand how?

Comment: Are you sure the second equation shouldn't be: $phi(y)\frac{d^2h}{dx^2}+h(x)\frac{d^2 phi}{dy^2}=0$? $h$ and $phi$ are functions of one variable, so partial derivatives are really either 0 (if on the "wrong" variable, with respect to which the function is constant) or reduce to ordinary (non-partial) derivatives (if on the "right" variable). For example, $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=\frac{dh}{dx}$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=0$ (and similar for $phi$).

Comment: Anyway, the grand idea here is - the original equation is tough. But it would be nice if we could find *some* solutions. Let's try with solutions which look like a product (function of $x$$\times$ function of $y$). Fine, this seems to work! But those are very special solutions, and they don't satisfy my boundary (or initial) conditions! But then, the equation is linear, so any linear combination of my solutions is also a solution. Maybe I can pack a linear combination of some solutions that *will* satisfy my conditions. Bingo! (Though I may need packing infinitely many terms - a series...)

Comment: @Stinking Bishop. Thanks for catching my mislabelling of the above sorry about that.

Comment: So they are just assuming we can multiply h(x) by the second derivative of phi with respect to y and vice versa for x, then add these together because that would be nice?  There is no property of derivatives I am not understanding?

Comment: No, there isn't. The key step is, however, the next one: divide by $h(x)phi(y)$ and you get $\frac{\partial^2h/\partial x^2}{h(x)}=-\frac{\partial^2 phi/\partial y^2}{phi(y)}$. So you have something on the left side that depends only on $x$ but not on $y$, and on the right side something that depends on $y$ but not on $x$ ... and they are equal! How is it possible? Only if *neither* side depends on *either* $x$ or $y$. In other words, both sides are a plain constant, and your PDE splits into two ordinary differential equations.

Comment: (However, you don't "multiply $h$ by the second derivative and add them because it will be nice" - you **start** with "it would be nice if $u$ could be broken up as a product of something depending purely on $x$ and something depending purely on $y$ - let's call those two functions $h$ and $phi$. The later calculation is just following that up. I also don't see any need to give those two functions *names* - they are only useful to find some very *special* solutions of the original PDE. A general solution is an infinite linear combination of those - something like a Fourier series.

Comment: @StinkingBishop can you copy an paste your first response into an answer pls so I can mark this answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I use $\phi$ instead of $phi$ - it will look nicer.

Anyway, as I summarised in my comment before, the grand idea here is this... The original Laplace equation is tough. But it would be nice if I could find at least *some* solutions. Let me try with solutions which look like a product (function of $x$ $\times$ function of $y$). Fine, this can be made work! But those are very special solutions, and they don't satisfy my boundary (or initial) conditions! But then, the Laplace equation is linear, so any linear combination of my solutions is also a solution. Maybe I can pack a linear combination of some solutions that will satisfy my conditions. Bingo! (Though I may need packing infinitely many terms - you may get a *series* instead of a linear combination...)

A bit longer explanation what's going on...

When looked that way, $h$ and $\phi$ are not some breakdown of $u$ that come from *physics*, they are two completely made-up-from-the-thin-air functions, $h$ depending only on $x$, $\phi$ only depending on $y$, and we hope to be able to find at least *some* candidates for those functions so that $u(x,y)=h(x)\phi(y)$ would be the solution of the original Laplace equation $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}=0$.

Now, what should $h$ and $\phi$ look like? Let's substitute them in the original Laplace equation and check. Note as $h$ does not depend on $y$, the partial derivatives of $h$ with respect to $y$ are $0$. Similar thing happens with partial derivatives of $\phi$ with respect to $x$. Ultimately, many terms in the twice-partial-differentiation of $u(x, y)=h(x)\phi(y)$ will just disappear. What we eventually get is the following:

$$\phi(y)\frac{d^2h}{dx^2}+h(x)\frac{d^2\phi}{dy^2}=0$$

where we really only have ordinary (non-partial) derivatives of $h$ and $\phi$.

Divide by $h(x)\phi(y)$:

$$\frac{d^2h/dx^2}{h(x)}=-\frac{d^2\phi/dy^2}{\phi(y)}$$

Now, the next trick (and a *key* step!) is to observe that the left side depends on $x$ but not on $y$, and the right side depends on $y$ but not on $x$ - but they are *equal* for all $x,y$. This is only possible if *neither* of them depends on either $x$ or $y$. Thus, both are equal to some constant $C$. Now this means that we can split the original partial differential equation into two ordinary differential equations:

$$\frac{d^2h/dx^2}{h(x)}=C$$
$$\frac{d^2\phi/dy^2}{\phi(y)}=-C$$

which are something that is routinely solved. Once solved, multiply $h(x)$ with $\phi(y)$ to get $u(x,y)$.

Now of course, those are very special solutions and they are bound to not satisfy any boundary or initial solutions that we may have. However, we have so far made a big progress, because the initial Laplace equation is *linear*. That means, if you happen to have some solutions $u_1, u_2, ..., u_n$, then any *linear combination* of those solutions $\lambda_1u_1+\lambda_2u_2+...+\lambda_nu_n$ is also a solution. Maybe we can now try to "pack" the coefficients so that we could get the solution which *also* satisfies the boundary/initial conditions. Even if we cannot do that, actually there are *infinitely* many "special" solutions of the above form (e.g. $u_1, u_2, u_3,...$), so we can afford to  try to find the solution in the form of a *series* ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda_nu_n$).

I don't have access to your book, but this is the essence, and I hope you will find some concrete examples (with concrete boundary and initial conditions) where the calculation is done to the end.

Comment: The ending statement is exactly what they were towards.